# Checkboxes and VBA

Tags: vba

I am trying to create a tool which has checkboxes linked with a live chart (the live chart displays the consumption of some items over a 5 year baseline) .

I used : https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/4034-excel-only-select-one-checkbox.html

as a reference but I am receiving 'User-defined type not defined' .I have attached the highlighted area which I am supposed to change.

My question is: with what?

[image: screenshot]

I am new to VBA and any suggestions will be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please [edit] your post to *embed* the code in the question itself, not a screenshot of it. Paste the code in the post, select the code block, hit Ctrl+K, done.

Comment: I presume your project has a reference to the `MSForms` type library? (Tools > References...)

Comment: Hi Mat! Thank you for getting back to me in such a quick manner!I am not quite sure what is the use of the references, or if I should have them within my process. :)

Comment: If I read your screenshot correctly, VBA is telling you that it doesn't know what `MSForms.CheckBox` is (hence "type not defined") - add a UserForm to your project, or add an ActiveX control somewhere on your worksheet, that will automatically add the `MSForms` reference to your project for you. Then try compiling (Debug > Compile VBAProject) and see if you're still getting the same compile error. Understanding the role of project references is kind of critical to understanding what's going on with this particular compile error.

Comment: Also when you edit your question, please make the title representative of the specific problem you're having, so that the Q&A is useful to other people. As it stands your question title serves little purpose and tells nothing about the problem you need a solution for.

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, Mat. I tried with a ActiveX control and it worked. I will also do the requested adjustments to my Q.

Comment: Please paste the code itself in the post, not just a picture of it. Select all the code amd press Ctrl+K to indent 4 spaces and make it format as a code block.